# correct replace using regex with similar text same start and end

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I want to comment piece of pretty similar text in document in Sublime using replace with regex.

Input:

```
@b =
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @e;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @c_historical;


@r =
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @f;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @y_historical;
```

Expected output:

```
@b =
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @e;
    /*UNION ALL
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @c_historical;*/


@r =
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @f;
    /*UNION ALL
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @y_historical;*/
```

I tried to use this regex `(UNION ALL\D*historical;)` and replace with  `/*\1*/`   (using Sublime)
but getting another result

```
@b =
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @e;
    /*UNION ALL
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @c_historical;


@r =
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @f;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      *
    FROM        @y_historical;*/
```

How I could kind of separate this 1 match to 2 different?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using -

```
((UNION[^;]*);)
```

Here's a link demonstrating how it works.

https://regex101.com/r/kpiVV8/1

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx is pretty close.  Just change it to a non-greedy quantifier by replacing `*` with `*?` will do the job:

```
(UNION ALL\D*?historical;)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJ0j09/1/)

The non-greedy version will give the shortest match whenever possible.  While your original greedy quantifier `*` matches as many as possible (longest match).  See [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) for a reference.